# -vf pp video filter: who is correct, the developers or the documentation?

Tags: ffmpeg, image-filter

I'm using `ffmpeg version n4.3.1-18-g6d886b6586 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers` and want to use autolevels on a video.

According to the [pp (postprocessing) filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pp) (section 11.172) I believe the syntax should look like this:

```
-vf "pp=al:f"
```

However, when I tried it, I got:

```
[Parsed_pp_1 @ 000000000736fb80] This syntax is deprecated. Use '|' to separate the list items ('al|f' instead of 'al:f')
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000072b7700] Error initializing filter 'pp' with args 'al:f'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

This syntax does work, as long as it's completely enclosed in quotations.

```
-vf "pp=al|f"
```

Could someone explain why there is a disconnect between the documentation and what actually works?

Answer (score 2):

## Use `|`, not `:` for this filter

The [pp filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pp) says:

> These options can be appended after the subfilter name, separated by a ’|’.

However, there is a typo later in the documentation. `[:f/fullyrange]` should be `[|f/fullyrange]`. This documentation for the fullyrange entry was accidentally forgotten to be updated when `:` was changed to `|` in 2013. See [lavfi/pp: switch to an AVOptions-based system](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=8da1fff85a90b2fad1310e629ed2056d6c43f50e).

If you want it fixed send a patch to ffmpeg-devel mailing list or [submit a bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: Well then, where is the current documentation?  I just went to https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pp again, and it still says ":" and not "|" .  If ffmpeg.org is not the source for the current documentation, what web site or resource does have the most current documentation?

Comment: tn/tmpnoise[|threshold1[|threshold2[|threshold3]]], temporal noise reducer

    threshold1

        larger -> stronger filtering 
    threshold2

        larger -> stronger filtering 
    threshold3

        larger -> stronger filtering 
                   V
al/autolevels[:f/fullyrange], automatic brightness / contrast correction
                    ^
    f/fullyrange

        Stretch luminance to 0-255. 

lb/linblenddeint

    Linear blend deinterlacing filter that deinterlaces the given block by filtering all lines with a (1 2 1) filter.